# Verificar se um parâmetro passado pela url existe dentro da View

Tags: php, codeigniter, get

Eu tenho esse seguinte código na minha `Controller`:

```
public function SetImageAndColor($client_id) {
if(isset($_GET['color']) AND isset($_GET['image'])) {
$dados['click2call'] [$client_id] ['image'] = $this->input->get('image');
$dados['click2call'] [$client_id] ['color'] = $this->input->get('color');
$this->session->set_userdata('click2call', $dados);
  }
}
```

O objetivo dele é salvar os parâmetros passados pela url (cor e imagem) na sessão. Correto?

Depois disso, eu preciso verificar dentro da `View`, se esses parâmetros existem, para poder chamá-los (Pois eles entrarão na personalização do site) . Mas já tentei de todas as formas (ex: `if(isset($_GET['color']))`). 
E sempre retorna que estes valores não existem, mesmo com eles sendo passados na url.
Este é o código da minha `View`:

```
<header data-color="<?php echo $client->click2call_color; ?>">
<h1>
<?php if($client->click2call_image != ''): ?>
<img src="<?php echo $client->click2call_image; ?>" alt="<?php echo $client->name; ?>"/>
<?php else: ?>
<?php echo lang('click2call_title'); ?></h1>
<?php endif; ?>
</header>
```

No caso os valores passados por parâmetro substituiriam `$client->click2call_color` e `$client->click2call_image`que são o padrão.

Tem algo de errado com o código?

Se não, como poderia fazer esta verificação?

Comment: você está usando algum framework? que tipo de view é essa? Pode colocar o trehco da view também em sua pergunta?

Comment: Uso CodeIgniter. Acrescentei o trecho como pedido. @GêBender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, você está querendo salvar uma certa configuração na sessão.

Mas, existe um erro no momento que os dados estão sendo salvos na sessão.

Acho que o corrento seria assim:

```
public function SetImageAndColor($client_id) {
    if(isset($_GET['color']) AND isset($_GET['image'])) {
        $dados[$client_id]['image'] = $this->input->get('image');
        $dados[$client_id]['color'] = $this->input->get('color');
        $this->session->set_userdata('click2call', $dados);
    }
}
```

Não precisa criar esse INDEX => click2call dentro de `$dados`.

Adicione uma função para obter o dado salvo na sessão.

```
public function GetImageAndColor($client_id) {
    $dados = $this->session->get_userdata('click2call');

    if(!empty($dados) && isset($dados[$client_id])) {
        return $dados[$client_id];

    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Acho que é desta forma que iria resolver seu problema.

```
$configuracoes = $classNome->GetImageAndColor(1234);

print_r($configuracoes);

// Array(
//     [image] => img.jpg,
//     [color] => #fff
// )
```

Comment: David, aonde adiciono esta última parte do código?

Comment: Provavelmente logo abaixo da função SetImageAndColor()

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!